# Javascript writing inside <p>

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a random fact generator which will be written inside a `<p>` tag. I followed every tutorial there is and I don't see where is the problem. The function is being summoned normally (i check that with alert).

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<p id="rfact" name="rndfact">random fact goes here</p>
```

JS:

```
function rfact(){
 var nrfact=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
 alert(nrfact);
 if (nrfact==0) document.getElementByName("rndfact").innerHTML="random fact1";
 if (nrfact==1) document.getElementByName("rndfact").innerHTML="random fact2";
 if (nrfact==2) document.getElementByName("rndfact").innerHTML="random fact3";
 }
```

Comment: You are selecting by the id `rndfact` when the id really is `rfact`.

Comment: `getElementsByName`, not `getElementByName`.

Comment: No that is not true @Karl-JohanSjögren. OP is selecting the element with the name. Be that it is `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementByName`.

Comment: Your third fact will never be selected.

Comment: Which browser you are checking ?

Comment: True, my bad. You don't see that so often so I missed it. There is no `getElementByName` as far as I know though, it's `getElementsByName` which will return an array with matched elements so an indexer is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no function called `getElementByName` on `document`.

You want one of these:

```
document.getElementById('rfact');
document.getElementsByName('rndfact')[0] // notice the plural
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a method that does not exist. There is not such method as `getElementByName`.

Use either `document.getElementsByName` (note the plural in elements, you'll get an array), or `document.getElementById` (which is the right way to do it).

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/P7wev/

Answer (score 1):

Use **getElementById**, since the **getElementByName** you supplied in doesn't exist nor does the **name** attribute inside the **P** tag.

```
function rfact(){
 var nrfact=Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
 alert(nrfact);
 if (nrfact==0) document.getElementById("rfact").innerHTML="random fact1";
 if (nrfact==1) document.getElementById("rfact").innerHTML="random fact2";
 if (nrfact==2) document.getElementById("rfact").innerHTML="random fact3";
}
```

Comment: Correct, `p` elements do not have a `name` attribute in HTML – and some browsers are strict about that, so even using the correctly spelled method name `getElementsByName` you might not get any result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("rfact").innerHTML=...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have an id set use that instead. `getElementsByName` returns an array, you have to access the return as such, by using the array notation before accessing the properties like `innerHTML`

**Using getElementById**

```
function rfact(){
   var nrfact=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
   alert(nrfact);
   var element = document.getElementById("rfact");
   if (nrfact==0) element.innerHTML="random fact1";
   if (nrfact==1) element.innerHTML="random fact2";
   if (nrfact==2) element.innerHTML="random fact3";
}
```

**Using getElementsByName**

```
function rfact(){
   var nrfact=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
   var elements = document.getElementsByName("rndfact");
   if (nrfact==0) elements[0].innerHTML="random fact1";
   if (nrfact==1) elements[0].innerHTML="random fact2";
   if (nrfact==2) elements[0].innerHTML="random fact3";
}
```

And use 3 instead of 2 in the formula to allow up to 3 facts.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML --> id="rndfact"**

```
<p id="rndfact" name="rndfact">random fact goes here</p>
```

**JS --> getElementById**

```
function rfact() {
    var nrfact = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    if (nrfact == 0) document.getElementById("rndfact").innerHTML = "random fact1";
    if (nrfact == 1) document.getElementById("rndfact").innerHTML = "random fact2";
    if (nrfact == 2) document.getElementById("rndfact").innerHTML = "random fact3";
}
rfact()
```

Use getElementById or use getElementsByName[0]

Comment: note that this will never show `random fact3`

Comment: @JanDvorak - same thing could be said of every other answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for ya.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload=function(){
rfact();
function rfact(){
 var nrfact=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
 alert(nrfact);
 if (nrfact==0) document.getElementById("rfact").innerHTML="random fact1";
 if (nrfact==1) document.getElementById("rfact").innerHTML="random fact2";
 if (nrfact==2) document.getElementById("rfact").innerHTML="random fact3";
 }

    }
</script>
```